# How to install apache2 in Ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I am trying to install apache2 in Ubuntu 12. I installed Ubuntu in Virtual Machine. I have problems. First, my system can not update or upgrade. When I type:

I receive a lot of errors like this:

```
Err http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.14 80]
```

At the final line, this is the result:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.13 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Second, when I try to install apache2. I type:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils
```

Again, it fails. The result:

e@ubuntu:/etc$ sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package apache2
E: Unable to locate package apache2-doc
E: Unable to locate package apache2-utils
e@ubuntu:/etc$

Can you help me plz?

**EDIT:**
This command does not work either.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal-backports/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the OS installation. 
use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`. If ou cannot update. Then try to re-install the OS. 
After a fresh install of your OS try `sudo apt-get install apache2 apache2-doc apache2-utils`